# Group output of single column postgresql

Tags: postgresql, filter, group-by

First off I'm a total SQL noob - Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

I have a FortiAnalyzer that uses a Postgres DB to store firewall logs. The Analyzer is then used to report on usage etc.

Basically I need to write a custom query that can show the Top 10 Users by bandwidth used for the top 10 Websites/destinations per user.

I can get all of the relevant information out of the unit, but I cannot get the output formatted correctly.

I would be happy with the output showing a username 10 times with the top 10 sites next to the username. First prize however would be to show the username in Column A only once, then in column B and C the destination address and bandwidth used respectively.

Here is the query I have so far:

```
select coalesce(nullifna(`user`), `src`) as user_src, 
coalesce(hostname, dstname, 'unknown') as web_site, 
sum(rcvd + sent)/1024 as bandwidth from $log 

where $filter and user is not null and status in ('passthrough', 'filtered') 

group by `user_src` , web_site order by user_src desc
```

Once the query is linked to a report chart, I them have options to limit output by x value. I could for example limit this to limit the user_src column to 100 (i.e 10 Users with 10 outputs each)

I hope this is clear to you... If not, I will do my best to answer any questions.

Comment: Give us a concrete example. http://sqlfiddle.com/ is a good place to build such. You can paste the link you get there here (without login).

Comment: Formatting issues would be better left to the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

I start with table aggregated on `website, user_src` level. Than it is not difficult to get top X users for top Y sites. You will need to use [window](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) function to get desired result.

Sample data:

```
create table test (web_site varchar, user_src varchar, bandwidth numeric);

insert into test values 
  ('a','s1',18),
  ('b','s1',12),
  ('c','s1',13),
  ('d','s2',14),
  ('e','s2',15),
  ('f','s2',16),
  ('g','s3',17),
  ('h','s3',18),              
  ('i','s3',19)
;
```

Get top X websites for top Y users:

```
with cte as (
  select
    user_src,
    web_site,
    bandwidth,
    dense_rank() over(order by site_bandwidth desc) as user_rank,
    dense_rank() over(partition by user_src order by bandwidth desc) as website_rank
  from
    test
    join (select user_src, sum(bandwidth) site_bandwidth from test group by user_src) a using (user_src)
)

select 
  * 
from 
  cte
where 
  user_rank <= 2
  and website_rank <=2
order by
  user_rank,
  website_rank
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6af5e/2)